# Angular JS select menu item appearing twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a select menu populated from an array of objects:

```
$scope.regionMenu = [
    {
      label: 'Show All',
      value: ''
    },
    {
      label: 'EU',
      value: 'Europe'
    },
    {
      label: 'Dest via Air US OB',
      value: 'Dest via Air US OB'
    },
    {
      label: 'Dest via Air UK OB',
      value: 'Dest via Air UK OB'
    },
    {
      label: 'Supplements',
      value: 'Supplements'
    },
    {
      label: 'Used Items',
      value: 'Used Items'
    },
    {
      label: 'YOIHIMBE',
      value: 'YOIHIMBE'
    }
  ];
```

And the menu itself:

```
<select ng-model="regionFilter.region" ng-options="s.value as s.label for s in regionMenu track by s.value"></select>
```

But for some reason I can't figure out, I have a blank menu item at top and "show all" is in there twice:

[image]

Why is this?

**UPDATE** Code generated in the html:

```
<select ng-model="regionFilter.region" ng-options="s.value as s.label for s in regionMenu track by s.value" class="form-control input-xs ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" xxx-ng-change="updateRegion()">
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option label="Show All" value="">Show All</option>
<option label="Show All" value="">Show All</option>
<option label="EU" value="Europe">EU</option>
<option label="Dest via Air US OB" value="Dest via Air US OB">Dest via Air US OB</option>
<option label="Dest via Air UK OB" value="Dest via Air UK OB">Dest via Air UK OB</option>
<option label="Supplements" value="Supplements">Supplements</option>
<option label="Used Items" value="Used Items">Used Items</option>
<option label="YOIHIMBE" value="YOIHIMBE">YOIHIMBE</option>
```

**UPDATE 2**

We did the filter this way to have both a text field and the menu filter:

```
<input type="text" id="countrySearch" placeholder="Country" ng-model="regionFilter.$" size="15">
```

Comment: Check the code generated by the select and post it

Comment: might be because of value: '', the default value of select box is ''.

Comment: @victorsosa Updated question with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) in AngularJS Documentation about Track By

> If you do need to repeat duplicate items, you can substitute the default tracking behavior with your own using the track by expression.

That's because you're using `track by` and associating to it's value, but it's label seems to be what identifies your menu.

Here's an example 
https://jsfiddle.net/nhkk98qf/2/

Comment: That did remove the duplicate, thanks.  I inherited this menu from someone else and I was unsure what I could change and have it still work

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that this is caused by including the Bootstrap JS into your app. Remove the Bootstrap and you'll remove your duplicate. Also, the blank option is created by Angular because you do not have a default value for your ng-model. Set that and your blank option will go away.

Comment: The rest of the project uses Bootstrap.  Also I have other menus which are not duplicating options.

Comment: For some reason I can set the default value of the model to one of the menu items ` $scope.regionFilter = 'Europe';` but the menu won't display the item.  And `$scope.regionFilter = $scope.regionMenu[0];` does not work at all.

Comment: You need to do it like this $scope.regionFilter = {
        region : $scope.regionMenu[2]
    }

Answer (score 0):

You might like to do it as follow in HTML -

```
<select ng-model="regionFilter.region" ng-options="s.value as s.label for s in regionMenu track by s.value">
            <option hidden value="">Show All</option>
</select>
```

and remove 'Show All' item from array in JS.

Comment: I need to have "show all" set the filter to empty, so all the items in the table are shown.  If "EU" is chosen only the countries with a region "Europe" show.  I then need to be able to re-set the menu to "show all"

Comment: It will work in that case also. You can reset using $scope.regionFilter = {
        region: null
    }

Answer (score 0):

Would you check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A5d8sAkTwdiL0TMbO44o) is that what you need?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="regionFilter.region" ng-options="s.value as s.label for s in regionMenu track by s.label"></select>
  </body>

</html>
```

I just updated your example. if you can share your `regionFilter.region`.
you can also check this [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

Comment: There is no regionFilter, it's just being used for the repeater: `<tr ng-repeat="i in filteredItems = (iso3166 | filter: regionFilter)">`

Comment: @Steve would you check my plunker and let me know if there is something wrong that I may correct :)

Comment: This does not work in my file:  `$scope.regionFilter = $scope.regionMenu[0];`  It causes the menu's data and the filtered dataset in the repeater to not load at all. Oddly, in your Plunkr when I choose "EU" the menu is then empty.  I need to choose something else, and then EU works.